# Magento 2: sales_order_save_after called twice after place an order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, sales-order

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 and tried to catch the data order using sales_order_save_after observer like this:

**etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
    <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderSaveAfter" name="vendor_module_observer_sales_ordersaveafter_sales_order_save_after"/>
</event>
```

**Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderSaveAfter**

```
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) { 
  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  if ($order && $order->getId()){
    $origState = $order->getOrigData('state');
    $curState = $order->getData('state');
    $oldStatus = $order->getOrigData('status');
    $newStatus = $order->getStatus();

    $this->_helper->customLog('OrderSaveAfter Observer', 'test.log');
    $stateLog = 'origState: '.$origState.';'.'curState: '.$curState;
    $statusLog = 'origStatus: '.$oldStatus.';'.'curStatus: '.$newStatus;
    $this->_helper->customLog('State Log => '.$stateLog, 'test.log');
    $this->_helper->customLog('Status Log => '.$statusLog, 'test.log');
  }
  return $this;
}
```

but i noticed , it logs the same things twice after place an order, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your Observer file:**

```
//Your code ........
protected $registry;
//Your code ........

public function __construct(
    .........
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    .........
) {
    ........
    $this->registry = $registry;
    ........
}

public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) { 
    $registeryObserverCheck = $this->registry->registry('registeryObserverCheck');
    if(!$registeryObserverCheck) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        if ($order && $order->getId()){
            $origState = $order->getOrigData('state');
            $curState = $order->getData('state');
            $oldStatus = $order->getOrigData('status');
            $newStatus = $order->getStatus();

            $this->_helper->customLog('OrderSaveAfter Observer', 'test.log');
            $stateLog = 'origState: '.$origState.';'.'curState: '.$curState;
            $statusLog = 'origStatus: '.$oldStatus.';'.'curStatus: '.$newStatus;
            $this->_helper->customLog('State Log => '.$stateLog, 'test.log');
            $this->_helper->customLog('Status Log => '.$statusLog, 'test.log');
        }
        $this->registry->register('registeryObserverCheck', true);
        return $this;
    }
}
```